# fscanf Error handling for unwanted input

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how you can handle some unwanted input with fscanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("../map1.map", "r");
    if (myFile == NULL){
        printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    char buffer[16];

    if (fscanf(myFile, "%15s", buffer) != 1){
        printf("The file is not formated correctly.\n");;
        fclose(myFile);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

I have this code. I want to make sure that I print an error and then exit out of the program in these scenarios (I dont care what happens with the overflowing characters I just want to exit):

1. Can't find/open the file. (This works)
2. The buffer gets overflowed. I dont want it to just grab the first 15 characters in this case. I want the program to exit. I also want to be able to continue reading the file later in the program. It shouldnt matter if there are more lines in the file. (This is the main issue).
3. I get no value at all (This works.)
4. I get 2 words (example: "hello" = 1 words, "hello world" = 2 words) (I cant figure this out either)

I want to know how I can test these things. What comparisons do I use etc.

Im not a very experienced user so please point out any obvious flaws and I will fix them.

To make it clearer. I dont want to make this work. I want to know how to exit out if it doesnt work. This works fine with the intended input.

Comment: First you need to increase the buffer. (`"hello world"` has 11 characters in length.)

Comment: Lets say I enter "hello world" in. How do I exit out since that will go over the buffer. That is one of my questions. I will try to edit the post to make it clearer though.

Comment: @JoelHansson I have added an answer for case 2. But can you clarify more on what should happen in case there are 2 words? Do you want to report failure and exit?

Comment: Yes I want to exit. Also I edited the post and responded to your answer clarifying some things.

Comment: @JoelHansson Clarify. If the file has more than 10 characters in it, what do you want to do? Put 10 characters into a buffer? Not put 10 characters into a buffer?

Comment: @Chitality If I exceed the buffer I want to print an error and exit the program.

Comment: @JoelHansson At no point should you ever exceed the buffer. As a C programmer, you must ensure that your program never writes past the end of a buffer. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: That is fixed with the %15s though right? If not then how do I do that? I want to exit out when that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2. You can do an early detection as -

```
int length;
fscanf(myFile, "%*[^\n]%n",&length);
if(length > 10)
    //exit with failure
```

You can then again compare length with `10`. Do remember to `fseek` back to where you were using

```
fseek(myFile, -length, SEEK_CUR);
```

For case 4 - since you already know the end all you have to do is read a word and check if you have read all as -

```
fscanf(myFile, "%15s", buffer);
if (strlen(buffer) < length)
    //return failure and exit
```

Comment: This means the file has to end though, right? There is more data in the file that I will have to continue reading in the program I will be using that for. I want to read just one line. I will edit the post to make this clearer.

Comment: As I said Im not really that experienced. Could you explain a little further how this works? (I am also really tired because I have been pulling an all nighter. So assume I am really stupid)

Comment: @JoelHansson I think you understood how I determined the end of the file. By seeking to the end and doing `ftell`.But since you only needed to go to the end of the line - I used "%*[\n]" with `fscanf`. This reads any number of characters that are not `\n` (end of line). Then the %n tells it to write the length read into `length`. This way you know how long the read is going to be. If it is more than your buffer length, you can discard.

Comment: @JoelHansson For checking multiple words. I first calculate end of line using previous method. Then read a single word using `%s` with `fscanf`. If the length read is less that the line length, it must be multiple words.

Comment: Ok I understand the multiple words thing. But I dont fully understand the "previous method" as you called it. 

When I do:
    int length;
    fscanf(myFile, "%*[^\n]%n",&length);

If I actually have a valid string. Where does that go?

Comment: @JoelHansson since we have put a `*` between `%` and `[...]` it gets discarded. Basically read but not stored anywhere. You have to do a separate read after verifying that the length is correct. This is like validating before reading.

Comment: So how do I get back to the start of the line then? "Do remember to fseek back to where you were." I still dont know what this means. I think I understand everything except that though.

Comment: @JoelHansson before doing this test do `size_t position = ftell(myFile);` and after the test `fseek(myFile, position, SEEK_SET);`

Comment: @JoelHansson or you could just do `fseek(myFile, -length, SEEK_CUR);`. Both are equivalent.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

At very first, your buffer needs to be large enough to store the characters read from the file, *including* the terminating null character:

```
fscanf(myFile, "%15s", buffer)
```

So your buffer needs to be *16* characters large!

Then for checking the string not to be cut off, read one character more(!):

```
char buffer[17]; // sufficiently large to store string + 0 character
if (fscanf(myFile, "%16s", buffer) != 1)
//                    ^ (!)
```

And then check the string length:

```
else if(strlen(buffer) > 15)
    // invalid string
```

Edit: handling the 'multiple words' problem...

Assuming you've read the word successfully as above, you need yet to check if another one follows. So you need to analyze the rest of the following whitespace:

```
for(char c = fgetc(myFile); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = fgetc(myFile))
//                                        ^ not the desired one
//                            ^ not end of file, we are not yet done
{
    if(!isspace((unsigned char)c))
        exit(-1); // undesired non-whitespace (-> multiple words)
}
```

As you exit anyway, you do not need to care about losing the first character of the subsequent word either...

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'l try to edit the post. But this doesnt answer my questions though. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, above answers point 2 (1 and 3 are solved already), remains point 4. How do you want to handle "hello world" (point 4; just wanted to add some lines...)? Do you want to read the words independently (-> loop) or into one single string (then fscanf is *out*).

Comment: If I get multiple words in one line when reading the file I want to report an error and exit the program.

So If I use that code and the first line of the file is "Thisisaverylongstringthatislongerthen15characters" will I catch that with your if()?

Comment: Exactly. But fscanf will stop at *any* whitespace, so you won't detect multiple words this way. Give me some seconds and I'll post something for this problem, too...

Comment: Oh I see. Since you have the space for an extra character if I exceed the desired length that character slot will be filled and I can catch it. I understnd. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
char buffer[32+1];//First prepare a buffer of sufficient length.
char word[16+1], extra_word[4];

if (fscanf(myFile, "%32[^\n]%*c", buffer) != 1 || //try read one line (or use fgets)
    strlen(buffer)>16 || //Examine the length or length longer than the expected format
    sscanf(buffer, "%s %3s", word, extra_word) == 2){//extra word exist ?
    printf("The file is not formated correctly.\n");
    fclose(myFile);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: What does this mean? "%32[^\n]%*c" Could you break it down for me?

Comment: @JoelHansson `"%32[^\n]%*c"` Read up to the newline within the specified size, and discard newlines (or extra single characters). For more information [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)